# Powershell New-ADUser Password Complexity Exception

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to mass import AD users from a CSV file. But I keep getting the following error:

*The password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirement of the domain*

But the password that's created with $InitialPassword has uppercase, lowercase, numbers and special characters so I don't get what it's not meeting.

```
ForEach($user in $CSV){

    $FirstName = $user.Voornaam
    $LastName = $user.Familienaam
    $DayOfBirth = $user.geboortedatum
    $Enrollment = $user.inschrijvingsjaar
    $Classroom = $user.Klas
    $PhoneNumber = $user.contactnummer

    # create and sanatize username


    $UserName = "$($FirstName.ToLower()).$($LastName.ToLower())"
    $Username = $UserName.Replace(" ", "")

    # generate password 
    $InitialPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "$($FirstName[0])$($LastName.ToLower())$($Enrollment)!" -AsPlainText -Force)

    New-ADUser -Name "$FirstName $LastName" `
               -GivenName "$FirstName" `
               -Surname "$LastName" `
               -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@{1}" -f $UserName, "arrow.local") `
               -SamAccountName $UserName `
               -Initials "$($FirstName[0])$($LastName[0])" `
               -DisplayName "$FirstName $LastName" `
               -HomePhone $PhoneNumber `
               -Description $Classroom `
               -Office $Enrollment `
               -AccountPassword $InitialPassword `
               -Enabled $true 



    Write-Host "$UserName"
    Write-Host "$InitialPassword"

}
```

Comment: [1] are you totally sure that the 1st letter of the `$FirstName` is uppercase? [2] have you visually confirmed that the actual `$InitialPassword` is what you think it is? your final line  should be showing just `System.Security.SecureString`.

Comment: Hi, yes the Write-Host shows that the password is what I intend it to be. Funny/weirdly enough, when I try the following it works: ```-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Bjacobs2020!" -AsPlainText -Force``` But when i change the string to a variable like so: ```-AccountPassword (ConverTo-SecureString $InitialPassword -AsPlainText -Force)``` It stops working eventhough ```$InitialPassword``` contains the same string

Comment: if `$InitialPassword` DOES NOT show `System.Security.SecureString` when you display its value ... then it is NOT a secure string ... and will give you errors when you try to use it as such.

Comment: Okay, I edited it and now ```$InitialPassword``` shows ```System.Security.SecureString```. But when I try to assign it to the password ```-AcountPassword $InitialPassword ` ``` it still keeps giving me the error I stated in my first post.

Comment: @SiennaSkies Can you update your code with the current edit, please? And can you confirm that NO account is created, even no disabled one?

Comment: @Thomas I updated the code in the first post. The first error has gone away but now I get an error saying _The name provided is not a properly formed account name_

Comment: And now the password error also somehow returned without changing anything to the script but it still shows the ```System.Security.SecureString``` output

Comment: @SiennaSkies - try to convert your parameter list to a splat [`Get-Help about_Splatting`] and then add a line that shows the content of the splat so that you can see all the parameters as they exist before sending them to the AD cmdlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default password complexity rules [disallow the account's name or username in the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements) - so when you compose the password of strings that also go into the Display Name, you're in violation of the complexity requirement!

If you're also seeing errors due to invalid user names, be aware that [`sAMAccountName` attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties#samaccountname) must be:

- Unique at the forest-level
- No more than 20 characters long

Comment: Hi, this indeed did the trick for the password. But it keeps giving the _The name provided is not a properly formed account name_ Although it seems to only occur with longer names.

Comment: @SiennaSkies DSA won't let you create a `sAMAccountName` that exceeds 20 characters

Comment: @SiennaSkies If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of it :-)

Comment: Did it :) But still giving me continuous errors after it worked 1 time with your fix